# How can we fetch google scholar citation through SERPAPI?

Tags: javascript, java, html, jquery, json

I have a number of authors name list and their e-mail id and i want to fetch their citations programmatically . So how could i fetch their citations using SERPAPI ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overlfow! Please provide more context about what it is that you are looking for. What have you done so far? And is this Java or Javascript? Consider reading [ask] and taking the [tour]

Answer (score 1):

You could use my library, [pyserpZotero](https://github.com/hack-r/pyserpZotero). It not only scrapes and parses the results, it also offers to export them as Bibtex, upload to Zotero, clean any raw LaTex, and download the free PDFs of any of your results that are also on arXiv.org

```
#### Build a list of search terms:
TERMS = ['reinforcement learning', 'traveling salesman', 'nowcasting', 'propensity score']

MIN_YEAR = "2010" # Oldest year to search
SAVE_BIB = False  # Save a Bibtex file (.bib)?
USE_ZOT  = True   # Upload to Zotero?
CLEAN    = False  # Attempt to remove/repair broken LaTex and other formatting 


#### Load libraries
from box import Box

import pyserpZotero
import yaml
    
#### Import Credentials from Your YAML File
with open("config.yaml", "r") as ymlfile:
    cfg = Box(yaml.safe_load(ymlfile), default_box=True, default_box_attr=None)

API_KEY = cfg.API_KEY
ZOT_ID  = cfg.ZOT_ID
ZOT_KEY = cfg.ZOT_KEY

#### Instantiate a serpZot object for API management
citeObj = pyserpZotero.serpZot(API_KEY  = API_KEY, 
                               ZOT_ID   = ZOT_ID, 
                               ZOT_KEY  = ZOT_KEY)

#### Call the search method
for i in range(len(TERMS)):
    print(citeObj.searchScholar(TERM     = TERMS[i], 
                                MIN_YEAR = MIN_YEAR,
                                SAVE_BIB = SAVE_BIB))
    print("This should've returned 0 (sucess)")
    # Upload the parsed results
    print(citeObj.search2Zotero())


#### Clean Ugly Raw LaText (as Much as Possible)
if CLEAN:
    citeObj.cleanZot(ZOT_ID      = ZOT_ID, 
                     ZOT_KEY     = ZOT_KEY,
                     SEARCH_TERM = "\\") # optional (defaults to all items)

#### Check Arxiv for Free PDFs of Papers and Attach / Upload Them To Zotero
citeObj.arxivDownload()
```

Docs: https://pyserpzotero.readthedocs.io

GitHub Repo: https://github.com/hack-r/pyserpZotero

PyPI Package: https://pypi.org/project/pyserpZotero/